# Cannot recieve incoming email on recently transferred domain - all MX records updated and have proper status

Tags: email, g-suite, email-bounces, mx-record

Domain Name: digiwhirl.com

Edition: Free edition

Affected Username/s: N/A

Issue Description: Cannot recieve incoming email on recently transferred domain - all MX records updated and have proper status

Steps to Reproduce (if applicable): Email bounces back if sent to any user on this domain. However, these users can send outgoing email to any other domain.

I changed the MX records for my domain for Google Apps about 30 hours ago.

```
    0 digiwhirl.com

1 aspmx.l.google.com

    5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com

    5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com

    10 aspmx2.googlemail.com

    10 aspmx3.googlemail.com
```

However, I am not able to get any incoming mail for domain.

I am able to send new email (outgoing).

I checked the status of my MX Records from a couple of lookup websites (Websitestuff & DNSStuff), and they say things are fine.
Updates:
On sending any email, the mailer-daemon responds back instantly with the following error:

```
Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550-mail-ey0-f177.google.com [209.85.215.177] is currently not permitted to
550 relay through this server. (state 14).

----- Original message -----

MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.14.11.199 with SMTP id 47mr3192398eex.87.1302707326011; Wed,
13 Apr 2011 08:08:46 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.14.48.67 with HTTP; Wed, 13 Apr 2011 08:08:45 -0700 (PDT)
X-Originating-IP: [120.63.31.108]
Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2011 20:38:45 +0530
Message-ID: <BANLkTinc0r8ZYGF-gO6VvG0w63C99P+6GQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: asd
From: *obfuscated*<*obfuscated*@gmail.com>
To: *obfuscated*<*obfuscated*@digiwhirl.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=0016364c7cc369c94e04a0ce2f1e 4/13/11
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's mail server is rejecting the message because, it would appear, that Google doesn't know they're supposed to be the authoritative recipient of those messages. The "clue" is the mention of relaying in the error message. That means that the recipient server is "seeing" the message as a relay attempt, not a local delivery attempt.

Are you certain that Google's service is configured for the correct domain name and all paid-up, provisioned, etc?

Comment: Yes, I've been poring over Google Apps settings for hours. All seems to be fine on their end.

Comment: @Hrishikesh Choudhari: I think you may have to attempt to get some support from Google. (Good luck getting a human, too... I've heard it's notoriously difficult to get human support from Google.) The rejection you're seeing is definitely coming from their server and is definitely because their server doesn't think it should be accepting the incoming messages.

Comment: @Evan: I've posted it on the Google Apps forum - http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=38dce21618569eaa&hl=en - If not this, and not SF, then it surely seems as a dead end.

Comment: @Evan: BTW, how do I even *start* to get human support from Google ?

Comment: @Hrishikesh Choudhari: I've only ever been able to get human help from Google thru a salesperson and, then, only a larger account (300+ users).

Comment: @Evan: I got it working!!!

The first record - the one with priority 0 and pointing towards my domain - had been messing things up. It should not have been there in the first place.

Comment: @Hrishikesh Choudhari: Hmm-- I didn't see that one in there when I looked myself y'day.

Answer (score 2):

While not the answer for Hrishikesh, I wanted to share another possibility for future visitors to this question.

I was encountering a similar problem after migrating DNS management to a BlueHost account.  It turns out there's a setting for the MX records **"Email Routing"** that you have to set the routing to **"Remote Mail Exchanger"** in order for the Google Apps email servers to accept the email.

Here's a screenshot of the correct setting that fixed it for me.

[image: BlueHost Email Routing Screen Shot]

Comment: This sorted the problem for me.   I had the MX entries in correctly to route me mail to google apps and the setting was originally to "Automatically detect" and I was getting 550 errors.  Changing it to the remote "Remote Mail Exchanger" setting in Cpanel fixed it.

Thanks @philip-faulconer

Answer (score 1):

Avoid bounced messages after changing MX records

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=45679

"Any time you change your MX records, it can take up to 48 hours for your new records to propagate."

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because you have `0 digiwhirl.com` in your MX records and possibly have emails accounts on the same server swallowing the emails.

Comment: Thanks @steve.. You're right, I removed that particular MX record and things were rosy again.